# Arduino code doesn't do anything without computer

Tags: arduino

Since the las few weeks I've been doing a project that involves communicating with a databse using GPRS module.

The testing went great when the Arduino was connected to the computer but when I disconnected it and plugged it to the wall using an adaptater it wasn't doing anything ( no data receive on the website ).

```c
     #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
     #include <Wire.h>
     #include <ds3231.h>

     struct ts t;

     SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); //Tx & Rx sont connectés aux broches Arduino #7 et #8

     void setup()
     {
     Wire.begin();
     DS3231_init(DS3231_INTCN);
     //Commence la communication Serie
     Serial.begin(9600);
     //Commence la communication Serie Arduino-Shield GPRS
      mySerial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("Initialisation..."); 
      delay(1000);

     mySerial.println("AT"); //Handshaking
     updateSerial();
     mySerial.println("AT+UPSDA=2,0"); //Reset connexion
     updateSerial();
     delay(2000);
     mySerial.println("AT+UPSD=2,1,\"sl2sfr\""); //Establissement de connexion avec l'APN
     updateSerial();
     delay(2000);
     mySerial.println("AT+UPSDA=2,3"); 
     updateSerial();
     delay(2000);
     mySerial.println("AT+UPSND=2,0");
     updateSerial();
     delay(2000);
        }

      void loop()
     {
        DS3231_get(&t);
        String heure = String(t.hour);
        heure += ":";
        heure += String(t.min);
        heure += ":";
        heure += String(t.sec);
      String Date = String(t.year);
       Date += "-";
       Date += String(t.mon);
       Date += "-";
       Date += String(t.mday);

       String Equipement = "STAINS";
       String Direction = "SUD-EST";
       mySerial.println("AT+UHTTP=0");
        updateSerial();
        delay(2000);
        mySerial.println("AT+UHTTP=2,1,\"www.projetwmr.site\""); // Parametrage URL d'acces
        updateSerial();              
        delay(2000);
       String command = "AT+UHTTPC=2,5,\"/add.php\",\"post.ffs\",\"vite="; // Commande d'envoi des donnes via POST sur PHP
        float Windspeed = 80; // Recuperation des données ANALOGIQUES
        // convertion valeurs en String - Chaîne de caractères
        command += String(Windspeed);
        // or convertion précise
        // command += String(Windspeed, 2);
        command += "&equipement=";
        command += String(Equipement);
        command += "&time=";
        command += String(heure);
        command += "&date=";
        command += String(Date);
        command += "&dire=";
        command += String(Direction);
        command += "\",0"; //Fin de la commande PHP POST
        mySerial.println(command);
        updateSerial();
        delay(1000);
        delay(10000);

    }

    void updateSerial()
     {
      delay(500);
      while (Serial.available()) 
      {
        mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
      }
      while(mySerial.available()) 
      {
        Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
      }
     }
```

Comment: To get the code to operate correctly I have to transfer the code again after I unplugged the arduino from the Computer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can't quite find out what are you doing with your GPRS module, also I'm seeing some problems with your code, for example, in `updateSerial` you are checking serial availability twice.

Anyway, disconnecting Arduino from a PC doesn't change anything except that when you are using the Serial which would be unavailable. So Your code RUN but doesn't work properly if it is disconnected from PC. It is because you are using default Arduino Hardware Serial which should be communicating with an external device (Like your PC). In your `updateSerial` function, you are checking the serial availability with `while (Serial.available())` and when you disconnect the Serial, this would become `false` and maybe it will explain the **"Not working"**.

Comment: But how can I send the AT commands to my GPRS without Serial ?

Comment: I'm seeing that you are getting some commands from the user and pass it to your Modem. So you can't, but if you tell me more about what you are trying to do, then I can help you to remove Serial input and handle Modem data inside the Arduino.

Comment: I'm trying to grab inputs from multiple sensors and send it to a database through a PHP file

Comment: Right now I didn't connect the sensors so I just simulated the variables with constants such as Windspeed = 80 or Direction = EST

Comment: If you want the user to input some values so you need a way to grab user data so Serial is one of them. But in general, you don't need to get commands from the user. Just grab the sensor value and create an AT command based on that and finally send that AT to the modem. If this will help you I would edit my answer based on that.

Comment: The AT command is ok for me but what I can't get to figure out it how to send the AT commands to the modem without the Serial

Comment: I didn't say that. Currently, you have two serial: 1. `Serial` which you read commands from User. 2. `mySerial` which sends commands to the modem. You can't remove the second one, It always needed, but you can remove the first one.